# How to make "Browse/save file as" dialog show over NSMainMenuWindowLevel

Tags: objective-c, macos

I had the need to create a window so it covers the menubar at top and the dock at bottom. So I had to `[NSWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1]` (if i did just `NSMainMenuWindowLevel` some of the corner items in the top right of the menubar would still show over my window so I had to go +1).

So now the issue is, a user right clicks in my window (which is a canvas drawing of an image) and then they select "save as", at this point I pop open the "Save as" dialog, but it is showing behind my window. Is there anyway to like find that just opened dialog window with objc and set its level to be above `NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1`?

Like is there anyway to make this panel open higher then this level:

```
var NSSavePanel = objc_getClass('NSSavePanel');
var savePanel = sel_registerName('savePanel');
var aSavePanel = objc_msgSend(NSSavePanel, savePanel);

var runModal = sel_registerName('runModal')
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try to do the opposite, to set the canvas to main window level, and when the nssavepanel closes to get it back to mainwindow+1

Comment: Thanks very much @user3351949 thats a good idea. But its a workaround I was trying to avoid :( because it doesnt look pretty :(

Comment: I understand i just thought that when user is focused on the save he is focused on the save... i will think about something else

Comment: You could to take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPanel/setFloatingPanel:

Comment: Thanks @user3351949 im reading that now :)

Comment: In anyway you can try to explicitly `[savePanel setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];` `NSPanel` is still a Private case of `NSWindow`

Comment: Thanks I tried that, i set it to `aMainMenulevel + 2` but no work :(

Comment: Have you tried `[sp setFloatingPanel:YES];` (Assume sp is your NSSavePanel)

Comment: Ah no I'll test that right away, thanks @user3351949

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90127/discussion-between-noitidart-and-user3351949).

Comment: Update to all `[sp setFloatingPanel:YES];` didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to defer the setting of the save panel's `level` until after the window is showing, which is tricky. You can do something like this (in Objective-C) *before* the call to `-runModal`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSApp modalWindow] setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
});
```

If you can't use GCD, you can use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a 0 delay. You'll have to use the selector of a method of your own. (You can't use `@selector(setLevel:)` because that takes a scalar, not an object, as its parameter.)

Comment: Ah thanks Ken Ill try htis out, is the `^{}` mean its a block?

Comment: Yes, that's a block. Also, I edited the answer slightly to indicate that you have to *schedule* the block (or selector) before running the save panel, because you don't get another chance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try both ways for learning purposes. With `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` do i have to 1) `objc_allocateClassPair` then to create a class in `NSObject` then 2) `class_addMethod` with SELECTOR_NAME a whose arguments are nothing, then 3) `alloc` then 4) `init` to get an instance of this class then pass to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` the selector `SELECTOR_NAME`?

Comment: Don't you already have some kind of controller object that you can just add a method to? That can receive the message and then turn around and set the level of the window. If not, then, yeah, that sounds more or less correct.

Comment: Thanks Ken, no we don't :( I don't think so at least. Cuz when I did the screensaver observer I had to do it like the way i said, this is my screensaver notif observer: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/35b03b79d48d56c2bce5#file-_ff-addon-snippet-objc_observescreensaverstarted-js-L140-L173